# how can we create a config file from a nested directory in python?

Tags: python, parsing, python-requests, config

I'm new to learning python and i've learned to push a config file data into nested dict. how is it done vice versa?
example fille would be like:

i need

dictonary = { 'section1' : { 'name' : 'abcd' , 'language' : 'python' } , 'section2' : { 'name' : 'aaaa' , 'language' : 'java' } }

into something like this

[section1]

name : abcd

language : python

[section2]

name : aaaa

language : java

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output looks like a toml output. try:

```
import toml
toml.dumps(dictonary)
```

[toml - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/toml/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the module [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html).

```
import configparser

dictonary = {
    'section1' : { 'name' : 'abcd' , 'language' : 'python' } ,
    'section2' : { 'name' : 'aaaa' , 'language' : 'java' } }

config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
for section, pairs in dictonary.items():
    config.add_section(section)
    for k,v in pairs.items():
        config.set(section, k, v)

with open('example.cfg', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work and here's why:

```
our_dict = {
  'section1':{
    'name':'abcd',
    'language':'python'
    },
  'section2':{
  'name':'aaaa',
  'language':'java'
    }
  } 
def dictFunc(dictionary):
  ret = ''
  for i in dictionary:
    value = dictionary.get(i)
    ret += '\n' + i + ':\n'
    for j in value:
      k = value.get(j)
      ret += j + ':' + k + '\n'
  return ret
print(dictFunc(our_dict))
```

First, we declare `our_dict`. Then, we declare the `function` `dictFunc()`, with `one argument`; the `dictionary`.  We make a `variable` named `ret`, which we will soon `return`. We start by looping the `dictionary`, and declaring the `variable` `value`. It's the `dictionary`'s `second-place key` (i.e `{'name':'aaaa','language':'java'}`). We make sure to add the `key` (i.e section1) to `ret`. We loop our `second-place key`, or `j`, to get `j` and `j's current key`, or `k` (i.e, `name`.). Finally, we get `j's current second-place key`, and link them together in `ret`. We now `return ret`.